# How to add a custom View inside a custom notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I try to make a custom notification, where I can directly pick colors from.
For this I need to add a custom View (or a library component) to the notification.

I found a method to add a custom layout as a notification, but for that you need a `RemoteViews` instance, where you can inflate the layout. I saw in a video that a `RemoteViews` can only handle a some kind of Views.

Here what I have so far (not working, probably because RemoteViews can't handle the ColorPicker)

In my Fragment: (When a Switch Button is activated)

```java
RemoteViews notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getActivity().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
        .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
```

notification.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="64dp"
              android:gravity="center"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.thebluealliance.spectrum.SpectrumPalette
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification"
            app:spectrum_colors="@array/colors_notif"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

So...
Are there any possibilitys to create a custom Notification without using `RemoteViews`?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem like this, RemoteViews not supported any custom class.
RemoteViews just support android basic component like TextView, ImageView

I wanted to show customView with non-actionability, just display data into customView like show personal info like identifier card.

I created bitmap from customView layout, so calculate measureSpec, then draw the bitmap into canvas, finally set bitmap into imageView in notification-layout

Comment: Okay, that sounds Special, but okay . I will try something like this as soon as possible. I also thought about just adding ImageButtons with a Color to build my own ColorPicker 